# Laravel refusing to display in iFrame as "'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'."

Tags: php, laravel, iframe, laravel-5, x-frame-options

So I have built a form in Laravel and am hosting externally but I want to display this within a HTML page but am having issues with the X-Frame-Options.

The exact error message is:

```
Refused to display 'url' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.
```

I have seen on previous StackOverflow answers that this is due to FrameGuard Middleware but this has since been removed and the issue line of code is not in that file.

Laravel Version 5.3.

I have also tried to set the X-Frame-Options in the Nginx config file using the flooring with no result:

```
sed -i 's/http\ {/http\ {\nadd_header X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN, false;\n\n/' /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
```

This error is occurring in multiple browsers, tested: Chrome & Safari

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Set your header on the response from the frame to

```
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://example.com/
```

where example.com is the domain requesting the form.

You could use middleware in laravel to do this.

Generate a new middleware.

```
php artisan make:middleware FrameHeadersMiddleware
```

then in the handle function of the middleware you just created do something like:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;

public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
     $response = $next($request);
     $response->header('X-Frame-Options', 'ALLOW FROM https://example.com/');
     return $response;
 }
```

You can then add this to one of the middleware arrays in Kernel.php

```
protected $middleware = [
    App\Http\Middleware\FrameHeadersMiddleware::class
];
```

Or to one of the middleware group arrays if you want to add it only to specific routes.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this but did not work in nginx config file, is there anywhere else I could try it?

Comment: @littleswany does that header come back in the response from the form?

Comment: No the same origin option comes back even when set as in your answer in nginx so I think laravel is changing it

Comment: Try using a middlware to add the header to all outgoing responses.

Comment: how would i go about doing this?

Comment: In Laravel as of today I'm seeing both headers so this is adding an additional header rather than replacing it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is now not advised as an approach https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options#allow-from_uri

Answer (score 9):

In my case, **nginx** was the one preventing the access.

Run:

```
grep -ri "X-Frame-Options" /etc/nginx
```

And check the output:

```
/etc/nginx/snippets/ssl-params.conf:add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
```

After replacing **DENY** to **SAMEORIGIN** everything started working as expected.

Comment: Ty good sir, this was my issue as well.  I instead just commented out the line since my desire is to allow my page to be iframed anywhere